# Msql Left Join if Where not exists

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have the following query. It works great, except when the row for _billing_company does not exists.
Can I get some kind of a default or an empty value if `_billing_company` does not exist?
In the example below, the post with ID 1 will be shown, but not the one with ID 2, because there is no `_billing_company` column in `postmeta`.
I would like to get all posts, regardless of whether all of the meta_keys exist. How is that possible?

```
SELECT p.post_date
    , p.ID
    , m1.meta_value AS 'order_total'
    , m2.meta_value AS 'currency'
    , m3.meta_value AS '_billing_company'
    , m4.meta_value AS '_billing_first_name'
    , m5.meta_value AS '_billing_last_name'
FROM dawp_posts p
LEFT JOIN dawp_postmeta m1
    ON p.ID = m1.post_id
LEFT JOIN dawp_postmeta m2
    ON p.ID = m2.post_id
LEFT JOIN dawp_postmeta m3
    ON p.ID = m3.post_id
LEFT JOIN dawp_postmeta m4 
    ON p.ID = m4.post_id
LEFT JOIN dawp_postmeta m5
    ON p.ID = m5.post_id
WHERE p.post_type = 'shop_order' 
    AND p.post_status NOT LIKE 'wc-completed' 
    AND m1.meta_key = '_order_total'
    AND m2.meta_key = '_order_currency'
    AND m3.meta_key = '_billing_company'
    AND m4.meta_key = '_billing_first_name'
    AND m5.meta_key = '_billing_last_name'
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC
```

Tables:
dawp_posts

| ID | post_name | post_date | post_status | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Hello | 2020-03-03 | open | ... |
| 2 | World | 2021-01-01 | open | ... |

dawp_postmeta

| post_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | _order_currency | CHF |
| 1 | _billing_first_name | Daniel |
| 1 | _order_total | 10 |
| 1 | _billing_last_name | Boxero |
| 1 | _billing_company | Nonero Gmbh |
| 2 | _order_currency | CHF |
| 2 | _billing_first_name | Markus |
| 2 | _order_total | 50 |
| 2 | _billing_last_name | Nachinzki |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `LEFT JOIN`, conditions on all but the first table should be in the `ON` clauses:

```
FROM `dawp_posts` `posts` LEFT JOIN
     `dawp_postmeta` `m1`
     ON `posts`.`ID` = `m1`.`post_id` AND `m1`.`meta_key` = '_order_total' LEFT JOIN
     `dawp_postmeta` `m2`
     ON `posts`.`ID` = `m2`.`post_id` AND `m2`.`meta_key` = '_order_currency' LEFT JOIN
     `dawp_postmeta` `m3`
     ON `posts`.`ID` = `m3`.`post_id` AND `m3`.`meta_key` = '_billing_company' LEFT JOIN
     `dawp_postmeta` `m4`
     ON `posts`.`ID` = `m4`.`post_id` AND `m4`.`meta_key` = '_billing_first_name' LEFT JOIN
     `dawp_postmeta` `m5`
     ON `posts`.`ID` = `m5`.`post_id` AND `m5`.`meta_key` = '_billing_last_name'
WHERE `posts`.`post_type` = 'shop_order' AND
      `posts`.`post_status` NOT LIKE 'wc-completed' ;
```

I would also suggest using more meaningfull table aliases such as `mot`, `moc`, `mbc` -- that is abbreviations for what the tables mean.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, while it does nothing for performance, I find this easier to read...

```
SELECT p.post_date
     , p.ID
     , MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = '_order_total'        THEN meta_value END) order_total
     , MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = '_order_currency'     THEN meta_value END) currency
     , MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = '_billing_company'    THEN meta_value END) _billing_company
     , MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = '_billing_first_name' THEN meta_value END) _billing_first_name
     , MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = '_billing_last_name'  THEN meta_value END) _billing_last_name
  FROM dawp_posts p
  LEFT
  JOIN dawp_postmeta m
    ON m.post_id = p.ID
 WHERE p.post_type = 'shop_order' 
   AND p.post_status NOT LIKE 'wc-completed' 
 GROUP 
    BY p.post_date
     , p.id
 ORDER 
    BY p.post_date DESC
```

Comment: To avoid a second sort, change to `ORDER BY p.post_date DESC, p.id DESC`.